# Импорт Экспорт БД Android

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite

Итак: есть программа работающая с БД, и есть необходимость переноса БД между устройствами. Экспорт БД я реализовал, но как сделать импорт БД в программу?

Код экспорта:

```
 private void exportDB(){
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source=null;
    FileChannel destination=null;
    String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "your package name" +"/databases/"+SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
    String backupDBPath = SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение импорта:

```
private void importDB(){
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source=null;
    FileChannel destination=null;
    String newDBPath = SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
    String oldDBPath = "/data/"+ "your package name" +"/databases/"+SAMPLE_DB_NAME;
    File newDB = new File(sd, newDBPath);
    File oldDB = new File(data, oldDBPath);
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(newDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(oldDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Imported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```